# Styling Google Polymer's paper slider element

Tags: css, polymer, web-component, material-design

I have a form with a number of paper-slider elements. I would like to reduce the vertical space between each of them, but am having trouble tweaking the styles to make it work. Here is an example. I would like to have these controls extend no further than their actual visible elements so that I could have more control over their placement.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      :host { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
      :host .label { min-width: 150px; }
    </style>
    <div layout horizontal>
      <div class="label" self-center>RED</div>
      <paper-slider id="honest" pin="true" snaps="true" min="1" max="5" step="1" immediateValue="test"></paper-slider>
    </div>
    <div layout horizontal>
      <div class="label" self-center>GREEN</div>
      <paper-slider id="respectful" pin="true" snaps="true" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="1"></paper-slider>
    </div>
    <div layout horizontal>
      <div class="label" self-center>BLUE</div>
      <paper-slider id="knowledgeable" pin="true" snaps="true" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="1"></paper-slider>
    </div>
    <div layout horizontal>
      <div class="label" self-center>ORANGE</div>
      <paper-slider id="fair" pin="true" snaps="true" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="1"></paper-slider>
    </div>
    <div layout horizontal>
      <div class="label" self-center>PURPLE</div>
      <paper-slider id="likeable" pin="true" snaps="true" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="1"></paper-slider>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<my-element></my-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:host paper-slider { margin-top: -1px; margin-bottom:-1px; }
```

The problem is that the sliders are as close to each other as they can be. You *can* enter negative numbers, but bear in mind that things are going to start looking squished.

Comment: Thanks @ChargerIIC. Unfortunately when I do that, clicking in one slider causes another one to receive the click. I think a more pervasive change needs to occur with the slider design to reduce each slider's clickable area so they don't overlap.